# Как поместить код в функцию?

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста, как поместить данный фрагмент кода в функцию? Дело в том, что переменная в кавычках очень смущает.
Так же не могу понять, как её потом вызвать ??

```
this.up = [];
this.up.push(this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'up'));
this.up.push(this.game.add.sprite(900, 0, 'up'));
this.up[0].body.velocity.x = -200;
this.up[1].body.velocity.x = -200;
```

Comment: function название() { код }

Comment: дело было в том, что при вызове функции, должна передавать переменная с this, пример: this.up

Comment: Значит пихайте функцию в объект и вызывайте функцию у объекта - this будет этим объектом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно что именно вы хотите и что в конкретном случае `this`. Если предствить что this - это некий game, то код может быть следующий.

```
var game = this;

function up() {
game.up = [];
game.up.push(this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'up'));
game.up.push(this.game.add.sprite(900, 0, 'up'));
game.up[0].body.velocity.x = -200;
game.up[1].body.velocity.x = -200;
}
```

вызвать этот код можно просто:

```
up();
```

Так же можно контроллировать скорость, которая в Вашем случае равна 200

```
function up(velocity) {
    game.up = [];
    game.up.push(this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'up'));
    game.up.push(this.game.add.sprite(900, 0, 'up'));
    game.up[0].body.velocity.x = -velocity;
    game.up[1].body.velocity.x = -velocity;
    }

up(200);
```